# Creation of SCRAM credentials directly on zookeeper/Kafka

Tags: java, authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Typically kafka-configs.sh is used to create SCRAM credentials for authentication using this command

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=alice-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=alice-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name alice
```

Is there any other way to create these credentials, either directly on zookeeper or through Java?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Admin Client does not provide a way to create SCRAM credentials, What I did is  downloaded kafka binaries on to my node and run the above command using process in java.

```
Process process = new  ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"bash", "-c", cmdline})
                        .redirectErrorStream(true)
                        .directory(new File(directory))
                        .start();
```